# "Bad play" or "bad playing" to negatively describe someone's playing of a musical instrument?

Tags: word-choice

When someone's playing of a musical instrument is praised, we can write:

> They praised her playing.
>
> They praised her piano playing.

But in a sentence like this one, where the playing as an activity is being negatively described, it is grammatically correct to write this:

> Whenever she looked at her new neighbor, she was reminded of bad guitar playing.

Comment: I have heard **bad play** (more often **foul play**) used chiefly in sport. **Playing** in music can be good, bad or indifferent.

Comment: "Bad play" is in your title but not in any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to say it. When saying *playing* in that context it acts as a noun.